# Is there any different type of woman voice in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I am a C# developer.

for IVR Voice do we have any additional voice for women other than the default three voices?

Programmable Voice -> Text-to-Speech, Is there any different type of woman voice?

Except(man, woman, alice)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right, those are the three voices we have, though alice does support [26 different language/locale pairs which you can set using the language attribute on `<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say#attributes-alice).

If you want other voices, you can use other APIs to generate speech from your text and upload it as an mp3 file that you can use with [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play). For example, here's a blog post on using [Amazon's Polly as the voice on a Twilio phone call](https://alestic.com/2016/11/amazon-polly-text-to-speech/).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: * we are passing confidential detail to Amazon Polly, when we use third party voice do the data will be secure?

Comment: I don't actually know. You'd have to check the terms and conditions of Polly in AWS and see if matches with your data privacy policies.